# CSS- Something is wrong with radio button indexes

Tags: html, css, radio-button, css-transitions

Having a little issue with radio button selections. 
I expected the button selections to work without any issue seeing as I didn't do anything to tamper with the indexing of the buttons.
I don't know why but, the button in front of the pressed button gets selected instead of the pressed button itself. It's as if the indexing of the buttons are all messed up. Please run the snippet below and see if you could point me toward the right direction.

```css
.frame{
  background-color:#406bd8;
  display:flex;
  width:600px;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.radio-bar{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0;
  width:40%
}

.label{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding:1em;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#eee;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.label:hover{
  background-color:#658ae8;
}
.label:before{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#eee;
  border-radius:inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:scale(0);
  transition:transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-origin:center;
  z-index:-1;
}

.number{
  opacity:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:0;
}


.number:checked+.label{
  color:#406bd8;
}

.number:checked+.label:before{
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
  
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="radio-bar">  
 
<label for='input1' class='label'>1</label>
<input type='radio' name='radios' id='input1' class="number" checked>
    
<label for='input2' class='label'> 2</label>
 <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input2' class="number">
  
<label for="input3" class='label'>3</label>
<input type='radio' name='radios' id='input3'class="number">
  
<label for="input4" class='label'>4</label>
<input type='radio' name='radios' id='input4'class="number">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `.number:checked+.label` will select the label immediately _after_ the checked input. Just rearrange your elements so that the label is after the input in the HTML.

Comment: Work like a charm!! Thanks a lot man. If you could please add that as an answer, that'll be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [adjacent sibling combinator (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) will select the sibling only if it is immediately *after* the first element.

To solve your problem, rearrange the order of your elements so that the input precedes the label:

```css
.frame{
  background-color:#406bd8;
  display:flex;
  width:600px;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.radio-bar{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0;
  width:40%
}

.label{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  padding:1em;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#eee;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.label:hover{
  background-color:#658ae8;
}
.label:before{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#eee;
  border-radius:inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:scale(0);
  transition:transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-origin:center;
  z-index:-1;
}

.number{
  opacity:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:0;
}


.number:checked+.label{
  color:#406bd8;
}

.number:checked+.label:before{
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
    <div class="radio-bar">  
 
    <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input1' class="number" checked>
    <label for='input1' class='label'>1</label>

     <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input2' class="number">
    <label for='input2' class='label'> 2</label>

    <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input3'class="number">
    <label for="input3" class='label'>3</label>

    <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input4'class="number">
    <label for="input4" class='label'>4</label>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your selector `.number: checked + .label`
In your html code, the input is after the label but in your css you ask the opposite

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="radio-bar">  
        <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input1' class="number" checked>
        <label for='input1' class='label'>1</label>

        <input type='radio' name='radios' id='input2' class="number">
        <label for='input2' class='label'> 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```